# UWP - Remove Built In Startup

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

Everytime I launch my UWP on Windows 10, a blue square appears with a white "x" through it. I know that I can change that image in the Assets folder to change it, but is there a way to keep it from appearing altogether?

Comment: Last resort: Replace it with a screenshot of your initial app state.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. It would actually have to be the final shot of an animated series (I have a .wmv that plays first that's just a glorified movable wallpaper with some loading symbols) but I could make that work I guess if there is no way to remove it.

Comment: Make the splash all black or the same color as your application background.  Then fade in your main view quickly.  It'll look like it just woke up with no splash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. This originated with iOS apps where the Cocoa Touch framework displays a splash-screen image, or a screenshot of the application's last state, while it initializes the application - it's done to make the application "feel" faster.

When "Modern Apps" were introduced in Windows 8 Microsoft copied that design, though because application windows don't have a fixed size (compared to iOS) it isn't always possible to display a screenshot so many applications default to showing the app icon instead - this continues to be the default in UWP applications which are the successor to "Modern Apps" in Windows 10.

As UWP is a sandboxed platform with prescriptive development practices there is no way around this requirement or "feature" - i.e. you cannot simply hide your application until it's ready like you can with Win32 applications (where you're free to do what you want between `main` and `CreateWindow`).

However if you design your application correctly then the amount of time your window shows the splash-screen image or icon/logo can be minimized - take a look at Microsoft Edge, for example, which initializes very quickly (even from a cold-boot) in under a second on my machine - Chrome takes longer!